# $\int\limits_{x}^{x+1} |f(x-\frac{z}{a})| dz \le K$ with $a < 0$ and $0 < x+1 < -a$ and a $K > 0$ for every $x > 0$

Tags: real-analysis

It is $\int\limits_{x}^{x+1} |f(y)| dy \le C$ for a $C > 0$ and every $x > 0$.

Is that enough to prove the following?

> $\int\limits_{x}^{x+1} |f(x-\frac{z}{a})| dz \le K$ with $a < 0$ and  $0 < x+1 < -a$ and a $K > 0$ for every $x > 0$

I tried to prove it like this:

$\int\limits_{x}^{x+1} |f(y)| dy$, substitution $y = x-\frac{z}{a}$ for $a < 0$ yields:

$$-\frac{1}{a} \cdot \int\limits_{0}^{-a} |f(x-\frac{z}{a})| dz \le C$$
hence $$\int\limits_{0}^{-a} |f(x-\frac{z}{a})| dz \le -a \cdot C \le K$$
which means, that $\int\limits_{0}^{-a} |f(x-\frac{z}{a})| dz$ is bounded.

For every $x > 0$ we can find an $a < 0$ with  $0 < x+1 < -a$.

Hence

> $$\int\limits_{x}^{x+1} |f(x-\frac{z}{a})| dz \le \int\limits_{0}^{x+1} |f(x-\frac{z}{a})| dz \le \int\limits_{0}^{-a} |f(x-\frac{z}{a})| dz \le K$$

Comment: I would like you to clarify the order of quantification of the variables. What I understand is that in your hypothesis, you assume that there exists a $C$ such that for all $x$, the inequality holds. And in the desired conclusion, you are saying that there must exist a $K$ such that for every $x$ there is an $a$ satisfying the desired inequalities. Is that correct?